# Py2exe - Compile exe for 32 bit and 64 bit

Tags: python, 32bit-64bit, py2exe

I've been researching a bit, but need a bit of advice specifically for Py2exe apps. I'm on a 64 bit machine, but from what I understand I can compile in 32 bit format, and run on both 32 and 64 bit.

Now my question. To make an exe, I'm using py2exe. So from what I understand, you don't need a 32 bit environment, just a 32 bit compiler which means 32 bit Py2exe? So if I delete Py2exe and reinstall the 32 bit version of py2exe, it will run on both? Are there any other precautions I need to take?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically 32x/86x can be used on 64x, but when I used to fiddle around with running 64x on 32x/86x, it crashed the computer, so nothing really just use the 32x/86x compiler. So, 64x programs are one way but 32x/86x are not:

- 64x program -> 64x computer
- 32x/86x program -> 32x/86x computer
- 32x/86x program -> 64x computer

Long story short: just use Py2Exe 32x/86x.

Comment: Great thanks. I don't need to touch my installation of Python, right?

Comment: Ok, I should actually clarify this, py2exe, I believe, makes win32 (32x/86x) programs, but the bits it's refering to is the bits of python, I you have 64x python, go with 64x py2exe.

Comment: Right, but what if I'm giving this exe to 50 friends? I need to run it on 32 and 64 bit machines. Not just 64x.

Comment: It should work for them too, if you have a 32x machine, test it out.

Comment: I don't have a 32 bit machine, but from what I understand, the development environment doesn't matter. So far I understand I need Py2exe 32 bit, but I'm not sure about the bit version of my python. I wouldn't think it would affect it, as I think Py2exe just looks at the source of all my Python files, and doesn't actually execute them.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Python 32 bit and 64 bit on your 64 bit system.you need to install needed packages and **py2exe** for both **32** and **64** bit version of python separately. after you installed 32 bit, you must change Windows path of python to 32 bit to use it..after success 32 bit compile you can change windows path to 64 bit again.

**A Note about 32 and 64 bit:**
If your app require more that 2GB RAM( like scientific calculating,etc) use 64 bit version .else use 32 bit version.
Also you maybe do not need to use 64bit since windows will emulate 32bit programs using wow64. But using the (64bit) in 64 bit OS will give you more performance.
also note that some options of py2exe are not support on 64bit like *bundle_files*